# Default CListCtrl data is coming sorted

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I am reading data from file line by line and putting the tokens of each line in a vector tmpstrArr.Then adding the tokens for each row in CListCtrl but CListCtrl is showing sorted data in descending order.I am confused because while debugging elements are going in correct order same as available in the file.I want my CListCtrl data in original form as in the file and not in sorted form.Also i have checked properties window of the CListCtrl where sort=None is selected.

```
LVITEM lvi;
CString strItem;

m_listctrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("col 1"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);
m_listctrl.InsertColumn(1, _T("col 2"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 100);

for(int i=0;i<tmpstrArr.size();i++)
{
    strItem=tmpstrArr.at(i).c_str();
    lvi.iItem = 0;
    lvi.iSubItem = i;
    lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)(strItem);
    //lvi.iImage = i%8;// There are 8 images in the image list
    if(i==0)
    {
        lvi.mask =  LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
        m_listctrl.InsertItem(&lvi);
    }
    else
        m_listctrl.SetItem(&lvi);
}
```

Comment: So remove the `LVS_SORTASCENDING` style bit that you're setting in the creation code you're not showing? Or at least show us that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding each item with item position 0. So the last item you just inserted is always the first in the list.
See [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb761107%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

If you want to get the same order like in the array, you need to add the item with

```
 lvi.iItem = m_listCtrl.GetItemCount();
 // or use INT_MAX (see docu)
 lvi.iItem = INT_MAX;
```